# Generic type coercion in Swift 3

Tags: generics, type-conversion, swift3, swift-protocols, type-alias

I am unsure how to make the following work. (Swift 3, XCode8).

I am trying to make generic Node class that takes a state object and/or wireframe object as generic parameters, with the state object having a protocol constraint of being a NodeState.

I am get the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type Node<State, Wireframe> to type Node<_,_> in coercion
```

With the following code (should work in a Playground):

```
import Foundation

public protocol NodeState {

    associatedtype EventType
    associatedtype WireframeType

    mutating func action(_ event: EventType, withNode node: Node<Self, WireframeType>)

}

extension NodeState {

    mutating public func action(_ event: EventType, withNode node: Node<Self, WireframeType>) { }

}

public class Node<State: NodeState, Wireframe> {

    public var state: State
    public var wireframe: Wireframe?

    public init(state: State, wireframe: Wireframe?) {

        self.state = state

        guard wireframe != nil else { return }
        self.wireframe = wireframe

    }

    public func processEvent(_ event: State.EventType) {

        DispatchQueue.main.sync { [weak self] in

            // Error presents on the following

            let node = self! as Node<State, State.WireframeType>

            self!.state.action(event, withNode: node)

        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:

The following works - when I remove the Wireframe references:

```
import Foundation

public protocol NodeState {

    associatedtype EventType

    mutating func action(_ event: EventType, withNode node: Node<Self>)

}

extension NodeState {

    mutating public func action(_ event: EventType, withNode node: Node<Self>) { }

}

public class Node<State: NodeState> {

    public var state: State

    public init(state: State) {

        self.state = state

    }

    public func processEvent(_ event: State.EventType) {

        DispatchQueue.main.sync { [weak self] in

            self!.state.action(event, withNode: self!)

        }

    }

}
```

Now, how to add the option for adding a generic Wireframe object to the Node class?

Comment: Why do you need a separate `Wireframe` generic parameter? Can't you just use the type `State.WireframeType` in your class?

Comment: Thanks Hamish, that works.

Answer (score 0):

Applying what I suspect is Hamish's answer gives, which now compiles as expected. Thanks!

```
import Foundation

public protocol NodeState {

    associatedtype EventType
    associatedtype WireframeType

    mutating func action(_ event: EventType, withNode node: Node<Self>)

}

extension NodeState {

    mutating public func action(_ event: EventType, withNode node: Node<Self>) { }

}


public class Node<State: NodeState> {

    public var state: State
    public var wireframe: State.WireframeType?

    public init(state: State, wireframe: State.WireframeType?) {

        self.state = state

        guard wireframe != nil else { return }
        self.wireframe = wireframe

    }

    public func processEvent(_ event: State.EventType) {

        DispatchQueue.main.sync { [weak self] in

            self!.state.action(event, withNode: self!)

        }

    }

}
```